Land comes in tapped but untapped?
If I have a Gond Gate and I cast Circuitous Route do the gates still come in tapped or do they come in untapped because of Gond gate?

When your gate enters while you also control Gond Gate, you can choose whether they enter tapped or untapped. It does not matter whether it entered through Circuitous Route or any other way.
Both Gond Gate and regular gates have a replacement effect that act on the same event.

614.1d Continuous effects that read “[This permanent] enters the battlefield . . .” or “[Objects] enter the battlefield . . .” are replacement effects.

Since you control both Gond Gate and the gate(s) that entered, you can choose which to apply last (for each gate individually) and thus which one wins.
The "enters tapped" clause of Circuitous Route is not a replacement effect and thus will always be replaced by either Gond Gate or the regular gates, whichever you choose to win.
